# Double hashing constant 5?

Tags: java, hash, hashcode, double-hashing

Ive found loads of examples of double hashing all of the examples tell me that you have to use %5 when you hash the 2nd time.

My question is why 5? is it an agreement that you always use 5 or how does it work?

one example: https://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/326/00wi/handouts/lecture16/sld025.htm

Comment: what on Earth are you talking about??

Comment: @MK https://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/326/00wi/handouts/lecture16/sld025.htm look at the last 3 examples

Comment: please point to at least one example...

Comment: @MarcRasmussen sounds like you want to ask your TA

Comment: TA - Teaching Assistant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a hash table with N places, the idea is to use two independent hash functions h1(key) and h2(key) and then use the probing sequence

h1 % N, (h1 + h2) % N, (h1 + 2*h2) % N, (h1 + 3*h2) % N, ...

You want to make sure that the the greatest common divisor of h2 and N is 1, otherwise you do not reach all places in the table.

there are several schemes this can be achieved, for example:

- choose N as a prime and let h2 give a result in the interval [1, N-1]
- choose N as a power of 2 and let h2 give an odd number in the interval [1, N-1]

Comment: what is N? can you explain this example abit more?

Comment: N is the size of the hash table, i.e. the number of array elements. In the example you have mentioned in the question N=7.

Answer (score 2):

No. The second hashing function can be whatever you want it to be. Ideally, it should have an equal chance of reaching every cell of your hash array.

My guess is you didn't look up any examples for double hashing from a different source. The source you used decided to use `% 5` multiple times for simplicity.

Comment: How do you know that the 2nd hash will be able to each every cell?

Comment: That depends entirely on what you are using as the `key`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't always use 5, and you even don't always use % either.

In your example. %7 and %5 are your hashing functions.  However, in reality, they could be completely different functions.

This example uses %5 because it is simple enough for the example. The only real requirement is that the two functions are independent.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing.